# How to get method from Item.java file to CardListAdapter.java file?

Tags: android

I have created an `Item.java` model class with necessary getter and setter method but I cannot access those `getter` and `setter` method from my adapter class. I can't figure out what is the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciable.
I have post related classes below. if anything more needed plz comment.

**1) Model class: `Item.java`**

```
package com.shinysoftware.hp.androidswiperecycler.Model;

public class Item {

    String thumbnail;
    String price;
    String name;
    String description;
    int id;

    public Item(){

    }
    public String getThumbnail ()
    {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail (String thumbnail)
    {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getPrice ()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice (String price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**2) Adapter class: `CardListAdapter.java`**

import com.shinysoftware.hp.androidswiperecycler.Model.Item;

```
public class CardListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Item> list;

public CardListAdapter(Context context,List<Item> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View itemview=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_list_item,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

   final Item item=list.get(position);

   // BELOW IS MY ERROR LINE. I CAN'T GET MY METHOD (getName())

   holder.name.setText(item.getName());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView name,description,price;

    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public RelativeLayout viewBackground,viewForeground;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        thumbnail=itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        viewBackground=itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);

        viewForeground=itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your constructor of CardListAdapter you seem to be taking a list of ClipData.Item instead of your own class called Item

Comment: But i am getting error if i take only Item It says me to import Item.

Comment: Manually import it as: import com.shinysoftware.hp.androidswiperecycler.Model.Item;

Comment: Or change your class name from Item to ListItem (or something similar)

Comment: I did it I manually added file. Thank you

Comment: No problem dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `constructor` of your adapter should be like below.

```
public CardListAdapter(Context context,List<Item> list) {
this.context = context;
this.list = list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Item in adapter and your actual Item model are different objects just has same name, use better naming and UNIQUE for data models.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your adapter constructor with below one.
   Just need to remove the ClipData from second parameter.

```
public CardListAdapter(Context context,List<Item> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
```

Comment: I edited my code but i am still getting error.

Comment: Clean project then build it. and see... one more thing Please check the package you imported for the Item in the AdapterPage.

Comment: I successfully did  my program. The problem was I didn't import file.